# Kafka-connect cannot connect to oracle database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to create a topic in Kafka. When i send a Post request to Kafka-connect to create a topic, connector is created but topic is not created. When i checked the kafka-connect log i saw below error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:69)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread.updateTables(TableMonitorThread.java:141)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread.run(TableMonitorThread.java:76)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getConnection(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:211)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:88)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:66)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:523)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:521)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused, socket connect lapse 1 ms. /10.206.41.145 1521 0 1 true
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:161)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:81)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:169)
```

You can see my Post request below;

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_source_oracle_order",
    "config": {
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
            "connection.url":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.206.41.111:1521:ORCLCDB",
            "connection.user": "SYS AS SYSDBA",
            "connection.password": "123456",
            "topic.prefix": "oracle01-",
            "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
            "table.whitelist" : "SYS.oc_order",
            "incrementing.column.name":"order_id",
            "validate.non.null": false
    }
}
```

When i check the connector status, task list is also empty:

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_source_oracle_order",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
        "incrementing.column.name": "order_id",
        "topic.prefix": "oracle01-",
        "connection.password": "kafka_connect",
        "validate.non.null": "false",
        "connection.user": "kafka_connect as sysdba",
        "task.max": "3",
        "name": "jdbc_source_oracle_order",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.206.43.77:1521:ORCLCDB",
        "table.whitelist": "sys.oc_order"
    },
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "source"
}
```

I coud not solve the problem. How can i solve this?

Comment: You should create the topic, not let Connect do it for you... This seems like a network issue, not configuration. Are you able to connect `nc -vz 10.206.41.111 1521` from the Kafka Connect machine?

Comment: I think i don't need to create the topic. Kafka-connect can do it. When i used mysql database, topic was created. there was no problem. 
By the way, there is no problem in log files anymore. I don't know why but kafka-connect was trying to connect another server, not oracle database's server. After i restart the container,there is no connection problem. 
But topic creation problem is still resuming.

Comment: You should disable auto-topic creation on the brokers if it is not already... Connect doesn't know what replication factor or partition count you want your SourceConnector to create, for example, and the defaults often are not good enough